# How can I extract Looker Studio dashboards/data sources data using API?

Tags: looker-studio

I have some dashboards in Looker Studio on my company's user account.
I'm trying to track data **lineage** and **user access** from Big Query to other Google resources (sheets and dashboards), so I'm trying to use the Looker Studio API to achieve this.

Basically, I'm trying to dynamically track BigQuery table sources for each of my dashboards, but I'm having trouble to even access the API, via Python script or App Script.

The google-api-python-client I can use with a service account for BigQuery is not available for Looker Studio.